# Items in the list to be appeared in the descending order

Tags: list-view, ordering

I have list with date, agenda and documents columns. How can I show them in the descending order, so that whenever someone uploads a new agenda that one should be shown on the top of the list?

Comment: do you mean in the Edit Form?

Answer (score 4):

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-HA102774516.aspx).

You need to order by Created date field.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the List view and Sort By Created Date descending.

Answer (score 1):

Go to List Settings.
Scroll all the way down to the bottom, to the Views section.
Click on one of the views to modify settings.
In the next page, scroll down to Sort section. Change the sort by column. Update the view.